# controlling one player with other in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

if i have two media players in form1 and form2 respectively....how can i control the media player in form2 with media player in form1....so that if i pause media player in form1...the media player in form2 should get passed and if i scrub the seek bar in player1 the seek bar in player in form2 should move along with it...how can i do that.......means how to play single video in both players at once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends heavily on the media player control that you are using, but as a generic approach you can remove the build in control of the player and place them outside the control.

Then in each action, you should call a Sync function, to keep both in sync.
Something like this:

```
Sub Button_Pause_Pressed()
  Player1.Pause
  Sync( Player1, Player2 )
end sub

Sub Sync( SourcePlayer, DestinationPlayer )
  if SourcePlayer.isPaused then 
      DestinationPlayer.Pause  
  end if
  '' // etc.
end sub
```

If you can use WPF, is much easier, because you can bind the controls of both player to the same ViewModel object and keep both in sync.